# upload camera image to firebase

Tags: android, image, firebase, camera, firebase-storage

I need to store image from camera, and gallery to firebase. In my project upload from gallery working, but when i try to upload from camera nothing happens. When click on button you chose between gallery or camera. When take picture or chose image from gallery, in imageview i get picture. Then i click on save and if picture is from gallery then is saved to storage, and create child in database, but if picture is from camera it won't work. Is there solution for this problem?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Uri mImageUri = null;
    private Button btn,mSubmitBtn;
    private ImageView imageview;
    private int GALLERY = 1, CAMERA = 2;

    private StorageReference mStorage;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        mSubmitBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
        imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);

        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Upload");
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showPictureDialog();
            }
        });

        mSubmitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startPosting();
            }
        });

    }

    private void showPictureDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder pictureDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        pictureDialog.setTitle("Select Action");
        String[] pictureDialogItems = {
                "Select photo from gallery",
                "Capture photo from camera" };
        pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {
                            case 0:
                                choosePhotoFromGallary();
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                takePhotoFromCamera();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
        pictureDialog.show();
    }

    public void choosePhotoFromGallary() {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY);
    }

    private void takePhotoFromCamera() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA);
    }

    ////////////////////////////
    private void startPosting(){

        if (mImageUri !=null){

            StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("Images").child(mImageUri.getLastPathSegment());


            filepath.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                    DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();//push kreira uniq random id


                    newPost.child("image").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());

                }
            });
        }
    }

    ////////////////////////
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == this.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            return;
        }
        if (requestCode == GALLERY) {
            if (data != null) {
                mImageUri = data.getData();
                imageview.setImageURI(mImageUri);
            }

        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            imageview.setImageURI(mImageUri);

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: is this happening on naugat and above android versions ?

Comment: yes, on nougat version

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and this happens mostly on Kitkat and lower version.When the image is clicked than getting the bitmap file  directly try to do following way,

```
Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
        File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        FileOutputStream fo;
        try {
            destination.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
```

Also in the manifest file make sure you have declared the following permission too along with the READ_EXTERNAL

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Reason for this issue is because Android 4.4 (KitKat) has changed how permissions are handled on the SD card. So its best practice to make your own directory on the SD card to handle all files your app needs to write. This works for all the higher versions too.

Hope this helps.